# How can I sort records in a gigantic csv file by date(mm/dd/yyyy)?

Tags: python, database, sorting, date, csv

I have a csv file that is 3,642,197 lines long and i need it to be sorted from earliest date to latest date.

I wrote a program that searches the database, and writes every line that contains the "API" number the user specifies to a file that will be used for graphing later.  It's very important that it has the earliest dates occur first in the file, so I'm running into this problem:  Whoever put this giant file together used 3 different files from excel and combined it into one csv, so the dates aren't sorted.

If i can format the database so that all the earliest dates would be found first, i figure that would be the easiest way to solve the problem.

I am somewhat new to python and I'm trying to wrap my head around how i can sort this file by date.  I tried to do it in excel and libreoffice calc, but it exceeds the maximum row allowance.

Here is an example of the text in the file:

"01/31/1986","25003050040000","SHA","Shannon",121,"",0,0,1324,31,False,P,""

I have records from 2013 to 1986, and have to have them sorted, but have not been able to understand how this is done.  From what i have searched i cannot find anything that I can understand.

Much thanks and appreciation in advance!

EDIT:  the easiest way is with Linux/unix.  A simple sort command does exactly what I'm talking about.

Ex. Sort -t/ -g -r -k3 -k1 -k2 infile.csv >  outfile.csv

-t/ sets the delimiter, -g sort by numerical value, -r reads the file in starting at the last line. -k3 is the year field, -k1 is the month field, and -k2 is the day field.  It will sort by year, then by month, then by day.  If you need to sort a giant csv file chronologically, and it won't fit into excel, this is by far the easiest solution I have found.

Note:  if your data is comma separated and the field after your date field is a number, you will need to change the first comma delimiter to a / so it doesn't include the trailing data in the sort.

Ex.  02/25/1987,204928169562,62563959401,16375840 <-- this will need to be changed to 02/25/1987/204928169562,62563959401,16375840 so your data is sorted correctly.

Comment: How far have you got? Read the lines into memory OK and need help sorting them? Mostly know how to do it but don't know how to parse dates in Python? Can't write a single line of Python and basically just want someone to do it all for you? Knowing what you've done so far affects the answers.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/ (note the `key` argument)

Comment: I would rather stick to python if i can, but i might end up doing it if i can't figure it out.

Comment: @SteveJessop, I have been learning for a little bit.  I have been doing data parsing and database searching.  I wrote the program that searches the database by api number and writes the relevant data to a file.  I can write in python, i just don't know how to sort by date.  Don't need anyone to do it for me, but i appreciate the offer ;)

Comment: That is fewer than four million lines.  On an Apple II you would have a problem but on a modern desktop computer this isn't really "gigantic".  The simplest thing would be to just read in all the lines and sort them, and you have several answers showing how to do it.  I'm in a room with several computers, and the smallest amount of RAM is 4 GB.  Even with 1 GB of RAM you should be able to sort four million lines with no tricks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sed`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) and [`sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) for that task:

```
cat big_file.csv | \
sed -e 's,^"\(..\)/\(..\)/\(....\)",\3\1\2,' | \
sort | \
sed -e 's,^\(....\)\(..\)\(..\),"\2/\3/\1",' > sorted_file.csv
```

The first `sed` command converts:

```
"01/31/1986","25003050040000","SHA","Shannon",121,"",0,0,1324,31,False,P,""
```

to

```
19860131,"25003050040000","SHA","Shannon",121,"",0,0,1324,31,False,P,""
```

Then the lines are sorted lexically by `sort`.

The second `sed` restores the US date format.

The `>` puts the sorted text into a file.

---

If you want to use Python instead:

```
lines = ((line[7:11], line[1:3], line[4:6]), line) # tuples of (date, line)
         for line in open('big_file.csv'))         # that's a "generator"
sorted_lines = (line[1] for line in sorted(lines)) # sort tuples and omit date
sorted_content = ''.join(lines)                    # recreated CSV file
```

The idea is exactly the same as with the shell script.

---

I just noted that you can to this far easier using the `key` argument of sorted that [@user2864740](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864740/) mentioned:

```
content = ''.join(sorted(open('big_file.csv'),
                         key=lambda line: (line[7:11], line[1:3], line[4:6])))
```

Comment: Wow, this looks pretty foreign to me.  I will have to look in to sed and sort.
Thanks!

Comment: @Wykleph You're welcome. I translated the idea to Python. Essentially there is no need to "parse" dates or CSV columns. Just reorder the components into a `(year, month, day)` tuple. Pythons `sorted` function sorts tuples element-wise.

Comment: could you point me somewhere where i can get an understanding of key.  I'm trying to figure out what is happening and how it works.  I'm still in the procedural mindset and don't usually pack everything up like that.

Comment: The `key` argument of [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) takes a single argument. In our case that would be a line (in `sorted([1,2,3], lambda i: ...)` that would be a single number). The called function has to return a sorting key (I shortened the `def` to a [lambda expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda)). The returned key will be used to compare two elements of the iterable object supplied to `sorted`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach (perhaps not the most clever, but it'll work) is to read all the lines into a `list`. Then the data looks like:

```
# lines -> ['"01/31/1986",..', '"4/30/2000",..', ..]
```

Then [sorting with a *key* mapping](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) can be used. This establishes a mapping for each item of what the *real* ordering is. In this case it's a matter of turning "mm/dd/yyyy" into something well-ordered. Possible keys might be: "YYYYMMDD", a [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) object, or perhaps an epoch timestamp.

For instance:

```python
def lineKey (v):  # v -> '"01/31/1986",..'
    r = v[1:11]   # r -> '01/31/1986'
    return datetime.strptime(r, "%m/%d/%Y")

lines.sort(key=lineKey)
# or; lines = sorted(lines, key=lineKey)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the csv file, convert the silly date to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format so that they sort properly and proceed:

```
csv_txt='''\
"01/31/1987","25003050040000","SHA","Shannon",121,"",0,0,1324,31,False,P,""
"01/31/1986","25003050040000","SHA","Shannon",121,"",0,0,1324,31,False,P,""
"01/31/1993","25003050040000","SHA","Shannon",121,"",0,0,1324,31,False,P,""
"01/28/1993","25003050040000","SHA","Shannon",121,"",0,0,1324,31,False,P,""
"01/31/2013","25003050040000","SHA","Shannon",121,"",0,0,1324,31,False,P,""'''

import csv
import datetime

data=[]
for line in csv.reader(csv_txt.splitlines()):
    d=datetime.datetime.strptime(line[0],'%m/%d/%Y')
    data.append([d.isoformat().partition('T')[0]]+line[1:])

for e in sorted(data):
    print e
```

Prints:

```
['1986-01-31', '25003050040000', 'SHA', 'Shannon', '121', '', '0', '0', '1324', '31', 'False', 'P', '']
['1987-01-31', '25003050040000', 'SHA', 'Shannon', '121', '', '0', '0', '1324', '31', 'False', 'P', '']
['1993-01-28', '25003050040000', 'SHA', 'Shannon', '121', '', '0', '0', '1324', '31', 'False', 'P', '']
['1993-01-31', '25003050040000', 'SHA', 'Shannon', '121', '', '0', '0', '1324', '31', 'False', 'P', '']
['2013-01-31', '25003050040000', 'SHA', 'Shannon', '121', '', '0', '0', '1324', '31', 'False', 'P', '']
```

Comment: How would i go about reversing this?  Also, i did data.append([d.isoformat().partition('T')[0]+line[1:-1]) I think you made a couple typos.  What were you going for because i'm getting a TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects.  I'm trying to work through it.  Thanks.

Comment: To reverse it just change the line to `sorted(data, reverse=True)`. Not sure about 'typos'. It runs as is perfectly for me.

Comment: It's just in this line:

data.append([d.isoformat().partition('T')[0]]+line[1:]) the extra ] and the : are throwing me off.

Comment: Break it apart: `s=d.isoformat(); date_only=s.partition('T')[0]; e=[date_only]+line[1:]` and see what is giving you trouble...

Comment: ah, didn't i didn't have my first [ inside the append().  Thanks drewk